# Any shortcut key to indent code in developer console in SalesForce?

Tags: salesforce

I am newbie to the `salesforce` and its platform. I am developing so much code using `VisualForce`, but I don't see the way to indent the whole code like we used to do in Java using `Eclipse IDE` option `CTRL +A ,CTRL + i`

Is there any way to indent code on developer console?

Answer (score 3):

yes there is a way to intend the code.
please use **Shift + Tab**  to intend the code in developer console
Regards, 
Ajay Babu

Comment: What if I have written 1000 lines of code and code is not in proper format, then probably Shift + tab option will not be good. Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TAB to indent lines of code but you can also select the code you want to indent and then click SHIFT+TAB which will auto-indent the code. But if you are used to using Eclipse download the Force.com IDE (which is Eclipse but has the Force.com packages) then you're using and IDE you are already familiar with, you can find instructions here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE

Answer (score 1):

On the line to indent (or with lines highlighted), cmd+[, cmd+] unindents or indents.  With windows, assume it's ctrl+....

Answer (score 0):

Select all lines of code using `Ctrl + A` and then use `Shift + Tab`